# Running total of rows by ID

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I have a list of IDs, transactions, and the date of those transactions. I want to create a count of each transaction within each ID.

The starting table I have is looks something like this:

```
id  trxn_dt trxn_amt

1   10/31/2014  58

1   11/9/2014   34

1   12/10/2014  12

2   7/8/2014    78

2   11/20/2014  99

3   1/5/2014    120

4   2/17/2014   588

4   2/18/2014   8

4   3/9/2014    65

4   4/25/2014   74
```

and I want the end result to look something like this:

```
id  trxn_dt trxn_amt trxn_count

1   10/31/2014  58  1

1   11/9/2014   34  2

1   12/10/2014  12  3

2   7/8/2014    78  1

2   11/20/2014  99  2

3   1/5/2014    120 1

4   2/17/2014   588 1

4   2/18/2014   8   2

4   3/9/2014    65  3

4   4/25/2014   74  4
```

`Count(distinct(id))` would only give me the overall number of distinct IDs and not a running total by each ID that restarts at each new ID.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit and add a tag for the specific database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *SQL-Server* you can use **[ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** in following:

```
SELECT id,
       trxn_dt,
       trxn_amt,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id, trxn_dt) AS trxn_count
FROM   StarningTable
```

In *MySQL* you can do in following:

```
SELECT 
  t.id,
  t.trxn_dt,
  t.trxn_amt, 
  @cur:= IF(id=@id, @cur+1, 1) AS RowNumber, 
  @id := id 
FROM 
  StarningTable t 
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT @id:=(SELECT MIN(id) FROM StarningTable t), @cur:=0) AS init 
ORDER BY 
  t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

using Row_number we can achieve this

```
    Select *,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))trxn_count
 from Transactions
```